# How to style epub table of contents with DocBook/Oxygen

Tags: xslt, epub, docbook

I'm working with DocBook5, and Oxygen 13.1 to transform  DocBook5 xml files to ePub using ANT.

Works great, generally.

But I'm trying to figure out how to style the ebook TOCs so that the chapter titles and the chapter numbers aren't all underlined.

I think there should be a way to add a entry to my custom xsl that would say, "no underlining" or "just underline chapter title, not number." But I haven't been able to figure out how.

Anyone know a way to do that? Or have any ideas on where I might look?

thanks in advance.

DC Denison

Answer (score 0):

Epub files are simply zip files. If you unzip it, you'll see that what you have is basically an `xhtml` file with a CSS. Changing the style of the docbook is done using the CSS.

Of course, it doesn't make sense to unzip an epub file to change the CSS. You would use an external CSS, then add this to your customization layer:

```
<xsl:param name="html.stylesheet" select="'myAwesomeStylesheet.css'"/>
```

In your CSS, you can style it just like you would xhtml output, such as.

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

(I do not know if CSS classes [e.g. `div.toc`] are also in the xhtml output in an epub archive. If so, you'd have alot more control over the appearance.)